# What is the difference between counting plane tree and binary tree by Catalan numbers?

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, generating-functions, trees, catalan-numbers

**Problems:** Prove that the number of plane trees with $(n+1)$ vertices is $n-th$ Catalan number $C_n$.

For this problem: I have found a solution in a post on Mathstack [Prove that number of non-isomorphic ordered tree with 'n' vertices is nth catalan number.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2351676/prove-that-number-of-non-isomorphic-ordered-tree-with-n-vertices-is-nth-catala)

However, I wanna try another approach using the same argument as I used for the case full binary tree including $n+1$ internal nodes: "A tree $T$ with $n+1$ nodes has a root with two subtrees $t_1$ and $t_2$ have $n$ internal nodes in total. So there is $T_iT_{n-i}$ ways to form the two such subtrees". Taking the sum of $i$ from $0$ to $n$, we obtain the Catalan recurrence.

But for the plane tree, using the same argument seems to be unfeasible (figure below)
[image]

I wonder if there is any simple way to approach this problem. I hope everyone could give me some hints.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4248061/how-to-prove-the-number-of-ordered-tree-with-n1-vertices-satisfies-the-catala/

Comment: The number of plane trees with $n$ edges is $C_n$. $\tag*{}$

_Proof:_ Let $\tilde T_n$ be the number of plane trees with $n$ edges. Given a particular tree $t$, let $r$ be the root of $t$, and let $s$ be the leftmost child of $r$. Delete the edge connecting $r$ to $s$. All that remains is the subtree $t_1$ rooted at $s$, and the subtree $t_2$ rooted at $r$, so that $t_2$ has all of $r$'s children except for $s$. These two subtrees have $n-1$ edges total. Therefore, there are $\tilde T_i\tilde T_{n-1-i}$ ways to form two such subtrees.

Comment: @MikeEarnest Thank you a lot for the reference about the bijection approach. About your proof, I wonder what the "leftmost child" is.

Comment: There is an illustration at the duplicate question I linked. Referring to my answer there, if $T$ is the original tree, then the `A` tree is $T_1$, the `B` tree is $T_2$, and the leftmost child of $T$'s root is the root of the `A` subtree.

Comment: @MikeEarnest Thank you a lot. I have already understood everything perfectly.